pip install pyperclip have cache initiallization
during the install, pip install clipboard am getting below problem
i need solution for this problem
note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for pyperclip
  Running setup.py clean for pyperclip
Failed to build clipboard pyperclip
ERROR: Could not build wheels for clipboard, pyperclip, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for clipboard
  Running setup.py clean for clipboard
  Building wheel for pyperclip (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × python setup.py bdist_wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [68 lines of output]
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running build_py
      creating build
      creating build\lib
      creating build\lib\pyperclip
      copying src\pyperclip\__init__.py -> build\lib\pyperclip
      copying src\pyperclip\__main__.py -> build\lib\pyperclip

